# How to do a clean Uninstall of RailsInstaller on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-mountain-lion

Is it as simple as rm -rf /opt/sm or are there other folders I should be looking at?

What else do I need to change? Is there a clean uninstaller that I can download/execute?

I'm using RailsInstaller 1.0.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Uninstalling Engine Yard's RailsInstaller](http://rachelober.com/2012/10/03/uninstall-engine-yards-os-x-railsinstaller/)

If you are running an old version

`/opt/rix/uninstall.app`

Otherwise

`open /Applications/RailsInstallerOSX-Uninstaller.app`